# WebRequest in C#

Tags: c#

I am using web request object in C# to retrieve some data from server
http://xxxxx.staging97.com/api/xxx.xxx@gmail.com/123456/469-Course_36VYS75T-11-1440001458_VFC-V6.3.cbook/teacher/
Above URL format works fine in web browser and I got correct results, but when I using in c# it does not get correct results.  It seems URL modifies when sending the request

This is my code

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
string jsonString = string.Empty;

using (System.IO.StreamReader sreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
{
     jsonString = sreader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be OK. Now big dilemma. We can not do anything unless you post the *real* url.

Comment: What do you mean you don't get correct results?  What results are you expecting, and what did you actually get?

Comment: when I type in browser it returns correct result

Comment: but when call from c# different reuslt

Comment: The browser has login credentials stored.  Clear out the browser cache and saved passwords and you will get the same result as the C# client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works and this is the result:

```
public void webTest()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.staging97.com/apixxx@gmail.com/123456/469-Course_36VYS75T-11-1440001458_VFC-V6.3.cbook/teacher/");
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
    string jsonString = string.Empty;
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        jsonString = sreader.ReadToEnd();

    }
}
```

*jsonString = "{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Error: You don't have access to this course.\"}"*

It's the same what you see in browser. So what's your problem?

Comment: Browser returns  {"success":false,"message":"Error: This course was activated before."}    this is the correct result, I want to get

Comment: Not for me. And it seems that your client return the same String as for me? Then your check in the Webservice seems wrong. What are the preferences? Check on IP?